# Extract shape outline points from PNG image in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, shapes, outline

I need to implement contours detection function in my iOS game, which I'm writing using cocos2d 2.1
For example user will provide me an image(PNG transparent):

[image]

So, I need detect shape polygon points and create box2d body from them, and I will able to put this image to my box2d scene.

I expect to have on output NSMutableArray with arrays of points of each polygon detected on the image. 
Same do **PhysicsEditor**, here is result of it:

[image]

Here is also result using **VertexHelper**(shows wrong way of detection, as one polygon... ):

[image]

Also **SpriteHelper but without detection of other parts of image**

[image]

**My question is:** how can I do this? What way is better and faster? 
I was looking for a solution in google, however I can't find any that will fit my needs...

Comment: search for "contour tracing algorithm". Keep in mind that you'll have to ensure counter-clockwise vertex winding for Box2D, and that the shape may need to be split up into multiple shapes to ensure each individual shape is convex.

Comment: New box2d  http://box2d.org/ has: "Polygon creation now computes the convex hull. Vertices no longer need to be ordered." So, I as I understand counter-clockwise is not necessary?

Comment: Regarding "contour tracing algorithm"- can you please point me to some example in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally done this by using Chipmunk Autogeometry feature. Work like a charm.

Just using https://github.com/slembcke/ConcaveSprite/blob/master/ConcaveSprite/ConcaveSprite.m I've saved my time...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for a Sobel edge detection filter. Check out the [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework created by Brad Larson. It has an implementation of Sobel edge detection filter using objective-C which might be useful for you.

Comment: I've check this framework, however it's not what I need, because I need only outline of image.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to find most light lib, because most this libs are too heave and will increase ipa size.